# How to change the tick of the color bar legend to black?

Tags: plotting

Is there any option that allows one to change the ticks and borders of the bar legend in a density plot to black?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

<s>I don't see a way to style `BarLegend` from `DensityPlot` but there are some potential workarounds.</s> (Carl has shown how to provide the settings I show below directly in `DensityPlot`.)

```
bar = BarLegend["Rainbow",
  FrameStyle -> Red,
  TicksStyle -> Darker@Green,
  LabelStyle -> Blue];

Legended[
 DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}],
 bar
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The coloring of some of the options to `BarLegend` indicate that they don't work but they do:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

produces the bar seen above, even though `FrameStyle` and `TicksStyle` are colored red. It's  just something to be aware, it may mean that Wolfram Research aren't committed to making this work in future versions of Mathematica.

Another way to get more control of the color bar is to draw it yourself. Here's an example:

```
bar = ParametricPlot[
   {x, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
   Frame -> True,
   FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}},
   FrameStyle -> Red,
   FrameTicksStyle -> Darker@Green,
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow", #2] &),
   AspectRatio -> 10
   ];

Legended[
 DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}],
 bar
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks! It is a hack, but is should do the job!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, FrameStyle->Black]` instead of [`Automatic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Automatic) to color the frame (although as CE notes, the [`FrameStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameStyle) option will be colored red):

```
DensityPlot[
    Sin[x] Sin[y], {x,-4,4}, {y,-3,3},
    ColorFunction->"SunsetColors",
    FrameStyle->Black,
    PlotLegends->BarLegend[Automatic, FrameStyle->Black]
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is something of a hack, but you can steal the bar legend from `ContourPlot`. Like so.

1. Make a contour plot and select and copy the vertical bar legend.

   ```
   ContourPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
     ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors",
     PlotLegends -> Automatic]
   ```

   [image: grab_bar]
2. Assign the copied graphic to a variable.

   [image: bar]
3. Use the variable in your density plot.

   ```
   DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}, 
     ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors",
     FrameStyle -> Black,
     PlotLegends -> bar]
   ```

   [image: plot]